# Older version of Astah Community?

Tags: uml, use-case, astah

Recently I just made a Use case diagram in Astah, the new version, as part of a requirment in a project. But when I opened it at a different PC (and it's not my PC, I can't download a new version of astah in this PC either) that runs an older version of Astah and my file could not be read. I checked Astah's website, but I could not find any solution. 
 
 So is there a site or way I could download older versions for my PC? If no, is there a way to save my file as an older version much like msWord documents that could be saved as a 2003 version?